# Retrieve image from django

Tags: django-media

I am completely beginner in Django, trying to make a table, which gets data from the Django database(included image). Here before adding the image field in the Django model, all was working perfectly. but I cannot get an image from the Django media file(I also upload images with superuser and Django form both, and they worked perfectly). here is my approach below-

in **views.py**:

```
def index(request):
    table_data = TableA.objects.order_by('roll')
    index_dict = {'insert_me' : "hello this is from views.py",
                  'dynamic_table' : table_data,
                 }
    return render(request, 'app26/index.html', context=index_dict)
```

in **HTML**:

```
    {% if dynamic_table %}
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Roll</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
          <th>Password</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Profile Pic</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                {% for i in dynamic_table %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ i.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.roll }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.email }}</td>
                    <td>{{ i.password }}</td>
          <td>{{ i.address }}</td>
          <td><img class="profile-pic" src="{{media_url}}{{ i.profile_pic }}" alt=""></td>
          </tr>
                {% endfor %}

        </tbody>
      </table>
        {% else %}
        <p>sorry cannot load the data for technical error</p>
        {% endif %}
```

in **urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I've also set up MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT. From the Admin I can upload images and they are ok.
in **settings.py**:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Media')
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
```

Now my problem is nothings is show in the profile pic column in the table, even any error is not showing.
Please suggest me how can I get the image file from the database for my this uses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main reason the images where not being displayed was because the path to your media_url was not added into the `render` function. See below:

```
def index(request):
    img = Upload.objects.filter(file_type='image')
    index_dict = {
              'insert_me' : "hello this is from views.py",
              'dynamic_table' : table_data,
              'media_url': settings.MEDIA_URL
              }
    return render(request, 'app26/index.html', context=index_dict)
```

Give it a shot!

Comment: Glad to hear it!